# live migration in openstack-ansible

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

When I try to migrate from one compute host to another, I get an error
What is the reason for this error? i get same error.

**compute2**

> 2019-09-17 10:29:27.009 2371 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-]
>   [instance: ab64119d-d075-4c99-8687-788695711b32] Live Migration
>   failure: Unsafe migration: Migration without shared storage is unsafe:
>   libvirtError: Unsafe migration: Migration without shared storage is
>   unsafe 2019-09-17 10:29:27.506 2371 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-]
>   [instance: ab64119d-d075-4c99-8687-788695711b32] Migration operation
>   has aborted 2019-09-17 10:29:27.533 2371 INFO nova.compute.manager [-]
>   [instance: ab64119d-d075-4c99-8687-788695711b32] Swapping old
>   allocation on 0002f629-1480-4c71-b74a-eb9ca16f87d1 held by migration
>   ae674faa-49f0-4139-8eb9-966d842d8370 for instance

**compute1**

> 2019-09-17 10:29:25.626 2261 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.imagecache [req-7455f1fa-1821-4760-a38c-80ed4a7aa95a - - - - -] image e0d82262-e5dd-46f3-8747-8bb451a11f3d at (/var/lib/nova/instances/_base/993dda6ef2a8133a22deb14a205ae0d791dbd070): checking
>   2019-09-17 10:29:25.627 2261 INFO os_vif [req-7dfec421-606d-4923-a8f8-b4796ffdc155 b2223e6724d441dc9ceb01e2d93c42e2 a4d7dd39e119424781ff6cc62874381e - default default] Successfully plugged vif VIFBridge(active=True,address=fa:16:3e:78:d1:a2,bridge_name='brqb8d9540b-30',has_traffic_filtering=True,id=65ef51ba-8e72-44a2-9f45-ac3aa0ad2225,network=Network(b8d9540b-307c-490d-a99b-7ce565065a11),plugin='linux_bridge',port_profile=,preserve_on_delete=False,vif_name='tap65ef51ba-8e')
>   2019-09-17 10:29:25.665 2261 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.imagecache [req-7455f1fa-1821-4760-a38c-80ed4a7aa95a - - - - -] Active base files: /var/lib/nova/instances/_base/993dda6ef2a8133a22deb14a205ae0d791dbd070

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988). This is a programming site, not a [photography.se] site. We want to read&analyze your errors, not critique your use of color and perspective. See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/